# Is there a term for metaphors built upon double entendres?

Tags: metaphors, literary-techniques

I was thinking deeply about figurative language today, and I read a sentence that *must* be an example of a specific type of figurative language, but I didn't remember learning about it and couldn't find it on a reference I use.

The sentence, from *Street Love* by Walter Dean Myers, is:

> Could it even withstand the *voltage* of / His mother's *shock*?

Myers builds the metaphor of *voltage* off of one definition of the word *shock*, while also calling the other to mind, since the mother would be surprised/upset at this event.

It seems to me that there ought to be a word for this! Any ideas?

I found a similar example, too. It was used as an [example of parallelism](http://virtualsalt.com/rhetoric2.htm#Parallelism) on the site I was referencing:

> She liked sneaking up to Ted and putting the ice cream down his back, because he was so *cool* about it.

It ins't a metaphor, but it similarly uses both meanings of the word (*cool*, in this case). I thought it might be helpful as a clarifying example.

Comment: Btw, this isn't *double entendre*, it's just pun for fun.

Comment: I don't think there's a special term for the two processes, metaphor and double entendre/pun put together. You'd just call it a metaphorical pun. In some sense, a pun is kind of a metaphor anyway; there's a literal meaning and a related non-literal meaning.

Comment: *Paronomasia/Paronomastic writing,* if you want to get highfalutin about it.

Answer (score 2):

I would describe it as *wordplay* through the use of *puns*.

While not exactly the same, the following are all examples of [Tom Swifties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Swifty):

- "Pass me the shellfish," said Tom **crabbily**.
- "That's the last time I'll stick my arm in a lion's mouth," the lion-tamer said **off-handedly**.
- "Can I go looking for the Grail again?" Tom **requested**.

> A Tom Swifty (or Tom Swiftie) is a phrase in which a *quoted sentence* is linked by a pun to the manner in which it is attributed. Tom Swifties may be considered a type of [wellerism](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/84567/23608).
>
> The name comes from the Tom Swift series of books (1910–present), similar in many ways to the better-known Hardy Boys and Nancy Drew series, and, like them, produced by the Stratemeyer Syndicate. In this series, the young scientist hero, Tom Swift, underwent adventures involving rocket ships, ray-guns and other things he had invented.
>
> A stylistic idiosyncrasy of at least some books in this series was that the author, "Victor Appleton," went to great trouble to avoid repetition of the unadorned word "said"; elegant variation used a different quotative verb, or modifying adverbial words or phrases. Since many adverbs end in "ly" this kind of pun was originally called a Tom Swiftly, the archetypal example being **"We must hurry," said Tom *Swiftly***. At some point, this kind of humor was called a Tom Swifty, and that name is now more prevalent though incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

They're not really [double entendres](https://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&q=double+entendre&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=qHWgUJeGLYGp0QXh1oGYBA&sqi=2&ved=0CBwQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=7b36e5aac7eed2af&bpcl=38093640&biw=1223&bih=893) *(words or phrases open to two interpretations, one of which is usually risqué or indecent)*.

I would just say they're [mixed metaphors](https://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&q=mixed+metaphor&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=C3agUJSAKIGH0AXOtYFw&sqi=2&ved=0CBwQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=392691e68c9b048a&bpcl=38093640&biw=1223&bih=893) Even metaphorically, the mother's *shock/horror* can't meaningfully generate any *voltage*, and *cool/suave* dudes have a blood temperature of 37° C just like the rest of us.

It's often assumed that a *mixed metaphor* must be "bad" - but as OP's examples show, they can be used *wittily* (depending on how you define that - but at least, as *deliberate wordplay*).

Comment: If your temperature is 38° C, then you have a fever.  Average human temperature is 37° ± ½° C.

Comment: @tchrist: I vaguely thought the "nominal" value was 37.5°, but the easiest way for me to get hold of that **°** character for my text was to Google "body heat" (I just cut & pasted the first result). But of course you're right - the standard value is 37, so I'll change it.