# What is the meaning of this poem?

Tags: meaning

> I see I see said the blind man to the deaf woman over a disconnected telephone.

My daddy used to say this a lot. What does it mean?

Comment: Related question: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84554/origin-of-i-see-said-the-blind-man-as-he-waved-his-wooden-leg

Comment: It isn't a poem, just a humorous catchphrase punning on two senses of 'see'. My dad's version was _"I see", said the blind man who couldn't see at all._

Comment: Why would you consider this to be a poem?

Comment: @GArthurBrown It actually sounds a like like a [Koan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koan),  not 'poetry' as such but quite poetic!